# What is the regular expression for the language, {w | w does not contain the substring 11}

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, finite-automata, regular-expressions

{w | w does not contain the substring 11}

What I am thinking: $(0^* 1 0^* )^*$
Is anything wrong with my expression?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't confident of your answer?

Comment: No reason other than I am a beginner in the subject, and I just want to make sure.

Comment: Start trying some string, for example: does the string '0' belong to the language? and is it generated by your regular expression? And what about '11'?

Answer (score 2):

$0^*$ will generate any number of repetitions of $0$, and will also generate the empty string $\epsilon$.

So, the problem with your expression is that $11$ is also accepted, since we can write it as $$11=(\epsilon 1\epsilon) (\epsilon 1 \epsilon)\in (0^*10^*)(0^*10^*)\subseteq(0^*10^*)^*$$
To fix this problem, use the $0^+$ operator instead, which acts just like $0^*$ except that it doesn't generate $\epsilon$. Or, if you don't want to use it, you can explicitly write $00^*$ instead since $0^+=00^*$

---

Additionally, you will need only one $0^+$ and not two of them (since then it means you won't generate $0$ for example). Think about where it should go!

---

Also, as @Janmar pointed out in the comments, you will also want to include words that contain $0$'s but no $1$'s. Its not hard to do, so I believe you wont need my help doing it

Comment: We probably also want to include words containing only 0s